# Hosting a website

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

I have created a website using xampp(localhost) as one of the project in my college.Now our professor said we have to host it. So i searched for the free hosting websites. I got 000webhost.com as one of the website.I created an account; downloaded FileZilla using which I uploaded all my project folders.

Now I created database on 000webhost.com changing my code accordingly from localhost to server name , root to username; and password.

My Problem is that now how should i create a table for storing data.Because in my actual website ( on my pc using localhost) i created directly using phpmyadmin.

I want to create a single table once and use it again and again for example if a user inputs some details then I need to store their details.

So can anyone please tell me how should i create table directly on 000webhost.com??

Comment: Your question is off-topic for so many reasons.

Comment: Just export your database from local phpmyadmin then import the same database to your 000webhost account or you can import the only tables after creating the database within 000webhost account

Comment: @Suraj Ok..I m trying..tysm

Comment: Words of wisdom: Find another host. They are the pits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is really off-topic, I am going to answer it anyways.

Your webhost, should -if it supports SQL- provide you with the details for your mysql. So for example, if I had the host host.com, I would connect using their provided data, which **could** be db.host.com with port 3306. Just put those details instead of localhost to connect.

Then they should have a utility like PHPMyAdmin to manage the database, or you have to get one yourself (there is plenty of SQL managers out there!)

Update: 000webhost apparently has CPanel, on CPanel there should be a MySQL link which takes you to the utility.

Comment: Wohooo...Done Thanks a lot